# Meaning of 'long line of code wrapping within the editor' ( in Xcode)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Just reading a text on Objective-C at the moment on the verbosity of method calls in the language. It says that method calls and even method declarations are 'often split across multiple lines to prevent a single line of code from becoming so long that it wraps within the editor' (as well as for the sake of clarity).

Just wondering what code wrapping within the editor means? I know how text can be wrapped around an image in order not to interfere with the image and allow for flow but not sure about this.

Thanks.

Comment: All this really means is when the line extends beyond the edge of the window, it will "wrap" around to the beginning of the next line, which can be unsightly.

Comment: Have you tried to enter a very  long  line into the Xcode editor? There is also a "Wrap lines to editor width" option in the Xcode preferences.

Comment: "Wrap" means "soft-wrap". When a statement contains so much code that it runs all the way to the right edge of the window, it may automatically come back to the left again on the next line, possibly line-breaking at a point that makes the code harder to read. So, in the phrase you cite, what I'm referring to is the difference between _letting_ a long line wrap by breaking where it happens to hit the edge, vs. the programmer _splitting_ a long line into multiple lines by inserting a return in the middle so that it remains legible the way _you_ want it.

Comment: Look at the code examples in the book: you will see that I am constantly splitting statements manually into multiple lines to make them look good within the limited width of a printed book page.

Comment: By the way, if you don't understand me, feel free to ask me for clarification. That's more polite than making everyone speculate openly. I'm not dead yet, you know.

Comment: See "Line Wrapping" discussion in [Setting Source Editing and Indenting Preferences](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor_preferences/articles/setting_source_editing_and_indenting_options.html).

Comment: @matt I didn't mean to make anyone 'speculate openly' and I don't think there was anything impolite about my question? I do appreciate your work and this excellent book though and for that, thank you.

Comment: I'm just saying I'm happy to answer questions directly. I'm easy to find! Speculating about what I might mean is not necessary (though sometimes, of course, I mystify myself).

Comment: Well you are a wizard! I had no idea you would be on SO. I saw a youtube video of you speaking about swift and your ready, quick intelligence is really quite something. Anyway thanks for clarifying that.. you are awesome. If I can email you I would appreciate that but didn't find any link on your website. If you accept emails please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The text will wrap when the line of code is longer than the editor window is wide. Usually this is disabled in code editors and a horizontal scroll bar is displayed instead and the end of the line of code disappears out of view. Some developers prefer wrapping, most (in my experience) don't. If wrapping is off then long lines of code are difficult to grok so shorter lines are preferred. I don't think that objective-C cares about whitespace (I'm a C# kinda guy) so it's your preference that matters.